# Add content to cell when user clicks it

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, changelistener

I have a functionality in a JTable, that when user clicks the cell, it removes certain character in it (like when there's content `- Hello`, when user clicks it, it shows `Hello`). When it's no longer edited, it shows 
`- Hello` again.

My problem is that when some cell is selected (but not being edited yet) and I start typing  `Hi`, it doesn't remove the character, so the editable cell looks like `- Hello Hi`.

Same problem is when some cell is selected and user presses space key.

I want to add the functionality to the JTable, so that when the content of the cell starts to be edited (by any way - clicking/typing when selected/space key/and maybe there are more options I don't know about), I want to programatically change the content first. Another option would be removing it when the cell is selected (but then I have to remember position of the last selected cell, so that the character could be readded to it).

I've tried in propertyChange in class TableChangeListener:

```
 table.setValueAt(removeCharacter(table.getValueAt(row,column)), row, column);
```

but it doesn't work as the cell is already being edited and I cant change it.

Comment: It seems a bit confusing.. So basically you want the old value of the cell to be added to the text you enter in a cell? So there's no way of deleting what is in the cell from the start?

Comment: @Octoshape sorry if it's confusing, maybe better explanation: the table shows prices like "$5" "20€" and when user clicks the cell to change the price, I'd like the sign to disappear. When user finishes editing (clicks enter or by other way), I want the symbol to appear again.

Comment: ah well this makes much more sense! :) can you show me in which method of TableChangeListener you put the `removeCharacter` function?

Comment: I've put it in run() (which is called by processEditingStarted, and that is called by propertyChange), should I post whole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You will have to use your own implementation of Cell Editor to meet your own set of requirements.
2. So create a custom CellEditor implementing `FocusLisetener` and `ActionListener` and implement the `FocusGained` and `FocusLost` function
3. Implement the `actionPerformed` function too to update value on enter click.
4. Handling the Focus event is a little bit tricky. As it tends to update the cell wrongly. That is why i had to pass the reference table to the `CellEditor` as a constructor parameter and read the cell row, col on Focus gain.
5. To reflect the `- xxxx`: placing `-` before the cell value, try using a custom `CellRenderer`. Check out the [official tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for details with example. And the part of the credit goes to @mKobel.

An implemented custom cell editor for direction: assign it to your target table column and test.

**Giff of my test result:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

     public void setValue(Object value) 
     {
         setText("- "+value);
      }
  }

class MyCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
                         implements TableCellEditor,
                                    FocusListener,
                                    ActionListener
{
    JTextField textFeild;
    String currentValue;

    JTable table;
    int row, col;
    public MyCellEditor(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
        textFeild = new JTextField();
        textFeild.addActionListener(this);
        textFeild.addFocusListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return currentValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

        currentValue = (String)value;
        return textFeild;

    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        textFeild.setText("");
        row = table.getSelectedRow();
        col = table.getSelectedColumn();

    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

        if(!textFeild.getText().equals(""))
           //currentValue = textFeild.getText();
           table.setValueAt(textFeild.getText(), row, col);

        fireEditingStopped();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(!textFeild.getText().trim().equals(""))
           currentValue = textFeild.getText();
       fireEditingStopped();
    }


}
```

Comment: not this is painting artefact, controled by Renderer, right place to use Renderer, with `setXxx(" - " + getXxx)` == constructor returns value from REnderers constructor (Xxx, `Object value`, Xxx, Xxx)

Comment: @DropDropped for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTable in local variable

Comment: @mKorbel, please could you rephrase. sorry i haven't got you. I mean the OP wanted to use an editor to update the cell on text data input. From his question, i think he wanted some thing like this as the attached Giff suggest

Comment: 1. String value "Hells" is stored in XxxTableModel, by default JTables view shows "Hells", 2. TableCellEditor starting with "Hells" too, isn't it, 3. override value in XxxRenderer (e.g. setText for JLabel as rendering JComponent) and there add " - "  before value value from constructor, then JTables view showing "- Hells", XxxTableModel store only "Hells", TableCellEditor starts with "Hells" too

Comment: @mKorbel, ah now i got you. Yes in that case he will need a CellRenderer too. Actually i prepared this demo by focusing on this point: `Hi, it doesn't remove the character, so the editable cell looks like - Hello Hi`. It seems he wants `Hi` with the extra `-`: `- Hi`. Then OP will have to use a CellRenderer too for easier accomplishment. Will update the answer by recommending cell renderer

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not change the content of the cell at all.
What you need is to set on the table a `TableCellRenderer` that renders the cell values. Implement the cell renderer so that it shows the value "- Hello" (although your actual data could contain just "Hello"). The renderer just shows any component you want in the table. When user starts editing the cell, the renderer component is not shown. Actually you could also manipulate the editing component using a `TableCellEditor`.

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273883/add-content-to-cell-when-user-clicks-it#comment30244222_20273883):

> The table shows prices like "$5" "20€" and when user clicks the cell
>   to change the price, I'd like the sign to disappear. When user
>   finishes editing (clicks enter or by other way), I want the symbol to
>   appear again.

Although @Sage post is a really great and general solution (+1 for you :), in this particular case I'd implement a [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and [TableCellEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) using [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) which can manage the currency format matter, as follows:

- Set a generic number format to the renderer component: [NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance%28java.util.Locale%29)
- Set a currency number format to the editor component: [NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28java.util.Locale%29)

This way when the cell is displayed the currency sign will be shown but when the cell is being edited the currency sign will "disappear".

Take a look to this example of implementation:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class CurrencyEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

    JFormattedTextField editor;
    JFormattedTextField renderer;
    Integer clickCountToStart = 2;

    public CurrencyEditor(Locale locale) {
        initEditor(locale);
        initRenderer(locale);
    }

    private void initRenderer(Locale locale) {
        NumberFormat format = locale != null ? 
                                        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale) : NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
        formatter.setMinimum(Double.MIN_VALUE);
        formatter.setMaximum(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        renderer = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
    }

    private void initEditor(Locale locale) {
        NumberFormat format = locale != null ? 
                                        NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale) : NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

        NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
        formatter.setMinimum(Double.MIN_VALUE);
        formatter.setMaximum(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        editor = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        editor.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Tree.editorBorder"));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return editor.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        if (anEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {
            return ((MouseEvent)anEvent).getClickCount() >= clickCountToStart;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        fireEditingStopped();
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if(value instanceof Double){
            editor.setValue(value);
        }
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if(value instanceof Double) {            
            Color background = isSelected ? UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionBackground") : UIManager.getColor("Table.background");
            Color foreground = isSelected ? UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionForeground") : UIManager.getColor("Table.foreground");
            Border border = hasFocus ? UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder") : BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();

            renderer.setBackground(background);
            renderer.setForeground(foreground);
            renderer.setBorder(border);

            renderer.setValue(value);
            return renderer;

        } else {
            String message = String.format("Not supported for %1$1s class!", value.getClass());
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
        }
    }

}
```

**Disclaimer:** it may not work properly with Nimbus look and feel as UIManager properties are named different. I've tested it using Metal, Windows, Windows Classic and Motif.

Here is the code I've used to test it:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class Demo {

    private void initGUI(){

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Item", "Price USD", "Price EUR"}, 0);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Fender stratocaster", 1599.99d, 1176.46d});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Gibson Les Paul", 1299.99d, 955.87d});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Pual Reed Smith Standard 24", 1999.99d, 1470.58d});

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

        TableColumn priceUSD = table.getColumn("Price USD");
        priceUSD.setCellRenderer(new CurrencyEditor(Locale.US));
        priceUSD.setCellEditor(new CurrencyEditor(Locale.US));

        TableColumn priceEUR = table.getColumn("Price EUR");
        priceEUR.setCellRenderer(new CurrencyEditor(Locale.GERMANY));
        priceEUR.setCellEditor(new CurrencyEditor(Locale.GERMANY));

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(new JScrollPane(table));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().initGUI();                
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: +1, i have built a Giffer program to generate animated evolution test with Swing app. The animated Gif of my answer is a result of that. I will share it shortly as soon as i complete more test on it ;)

Comment: Thanks! That's awesome! I'll be happy to give it a try :) @Sage